# Rebase without changing content

Tags: git, git-rebase

Is there a simple option to `git rebase` that says: “Rewrite this history, automatically resolving all conflicts in such a way that the *content* of HEAD after the rebase will remain the same as it is now”?

I have a feature branch and I have merged in master; essentially I’d like to redo that as a rebase onto master.

I thought that `-X ours` might be that option, but the result was different content.

Comment: If i understand correctly, you want to use `git rebase` to achieve the result of `git merge feature_branch` without having to resolve the conflicts while rebasing?

Comment: Well, the idea is that all the conflicts were already resolved as part of the merge; the content resulting from "rebase" should be the same.  It's more like I want to re-use the conflict resolutions.

Comment: Who do you want to win when a conflict arises? Your branch or the branch you are merging? It has to choose one, and you are right the -X option is the way to go.

Comment: if you already did a merge, I don't understand why the rebase...

Comment: @bitoiu pickiness about the appearance of the git history, I guess...

Comment: but if you did a merge, the rebase unless an interactive one, will not change the conflict solving merge? Maybe I'm missing the point. If you already did the merge, just do rebase -i until an older commit before the merge-base, and see if that helps, you can change the history as you see fit. Note: if you pushed these changes, well, then there's nothing that can help you -pretending we don't know about fp ;)

Comment: I get what you're saying.. Once you merge your tree looks well merged. But on applying a rebase on the merged tree you can rewrite the history to be a linear without all the messy branches.

Comment: @PraveenramBalachandar That's exactly right...

Comment: I don't see how this would possibly work without also squashing the commits from the feature branch into a single commit, as described by Greg Bacon. The intermediate commits can contain any number of conflicts which are impossible to automatically resolve in such a fashion that will eventually lead up to the contents of `HEAD`.

Comment: I just did something similar. I just git reset --soft from my feature branch to my master. Then I checked in the staged files into master as a new commit.

Answer (score 4):

As I understand it, what you want isn’t exactly a merge or a rebase. It’s more of a cut-over. You have already merged master into your feature, so you know what you want the resulting tree to be.

In git terms, this means you want your new commit to use the same tree as the head of your feature branch. Assuming your feature branch is named my-feature, then you can directly address that commit’s tree root with `my-feature^{tree}`.

You want a new commit whose parent is your master and whose tree reuses one that already exists in your repository. The plumbing command [`git commit-tree`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit-tree.html) lets you exercise this fine level of control.

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge --ff-only \
  $(git commit-tree my-feature^{tree} -p $(git rev-parse master) -m FIXME)
$ git commit --amend -C $(git rev-parse my-feature)
```

The output of `git commit-tree` is the SHA1 of the new commit. The `git merge` command captures that SHA1 and merges it into your local master. The `--ff-only` is there as sort of a fail safe and to express our intent. The new commit will be a fast-forward by construction due to naming master as its parent with `-p`.

The `-C` option to `git commit` allows you to reuse the commit message from another commit, the head of your feature branch in the above case.

Comment: Note that this approach will not preserve your history. Instead, all changes will be squashed into a single commit.